# How to change keyboard language if a specific keyboard is connected? (Win 10/11)

Tags: windows, operating-system, keyboard, settings

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question... however:

Does exist a way to tell Windows (10/11) to switch keyboard language dynamically when I plug in a specific keyboard?

My problem is that I have an Italian keyboard layout on my laptop, and I just bought a mechanical keyboard for the office, which has United States layout; totally fine to me, I'm already used to American layout because I have already another similar mechanical keyboard at home.
Of course I switched the OS language layout to fit the keyboard (default os language was Italian), BUT if I unplug the keyboard from the computer, I have to switch system keyboard language layout MANUALLY...
Is there a way to tell Windows to use American layout only if the external keyboard is plugged (change the preference automatically)?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: If you don't intend to write it yourself then this is the wrong website indeed, try SuperUser.com

Comment: As there are only two keys to press to switch languages, the time to make a script/program is relatively large. `Keyboard shortcut:  To switch between keyboard layouts, press Alt+Shift.` Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258

Comment: @Anders actually I'm a developer, I'm curious if there's a way to program this feature by my self.

Comment: @An-dir Yes I read about the shortcuts and you're right. I'm just curious if there's a way to achieve the result anyway :)

Comment: WM_DEVICECHANGE to detect probably. Have you looked at the keyboard functions on MSDN to see what it offers to change?

Comment: What languages do you code? Did you actually Code something? Did you even Google? I found an application with code for you that also explains why it is difficult: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20994/Using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-layouts-on